# how to check protocol present in url or not?

Tags: java, protocols

how to check protocol is present in URL , if not present need to append it.
is there any class to achieve this in java?
eg: String URL = www.google.com

need to get http://www.google.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have `String url = www.google.com`. String class methods would be enough for the goal of checking protocol identifiers.  For example, `url.startsWith("https://")` would check whether a specific string is starting with the given protocol name.

However, are these controls enough for validation?

I think they **aren't** enough. First of all, you should define a list of valid protocol identifiers, e.g. a String array like `{"http", "ftp", "https", ...`}. Then you can parse your input String with regex `("://")` and test your URL header whether it belongs to the list of valid protocol identifiers. And domain name validation methods are beyond this question, you can/should handle it with different techniques as well.

Comment: Just for completeness, I would do something like the following:
'
private static boolean isUrlHttps(String url){
    if(Strings.isNullOrEmpty(url))
        return false;
    return url.toLowerCase().startsWith("https://");
}'

Answer (score 4):

Just use `String.startsWith("http://")` to check this.

```
public String ensure_has_protocol(final String a_url)
{
    if (!a_url.startsWith("http://"))
    {
        return "http://" + a_url;
    }
    return a_url;
}
```

EDIT:

An alternative would use a `java.net.URL` instance, whose constructor would throw an `java.net.MalformedURLException` if the URL did not contain a (legal) protocol (or was invalid for any other reason):

```
public URL make_url(final String a_url) throws MalformedURLException
{
    try
    {
        return new URL(a_url);
    }
    catch (final MalformedURLException e)
    {
    }
    return new URL("http://" + a_url);
}
```

You can use `URL.toString()` to obtain string representation of the URL. This is an improvement on the `startsWith()` approach as it guarantees that return URL is valid.

Comment: `!a_url.matches("\\w+\\:.*")` for `https`, `file` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, I would do something like the following:

```
import com.google.common.base.Strings;

private static boolean isUrlHttps(String url){
    if(Strings.isNullOrEmpty(url))
        return false;
    return url.toLowerCase().startsWith("https://");
}
```